# Multiple Joins and the result needs to be distinct and/or grouped

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL query working...almost.  The result I get is this:

- Photo Op
- Photo Op
- ANY Item Autograph
- ANY Item Autograph

**What I'd like to get is this:**

- Photo Op
- ANY Item Autograph

Here's my code:

```
SQL = "SELECT * "
SQL = SQL + "FROM dbo.event "
SQL = SQL + "JOIN dbo.player_schedule "
SQL = SQL + "ON dbo.event.id=dbo.player_schedule.id_event "
SQL = SQL + "JOIN dbo.player "
SQL = SQL + "ON dbo.player_schedule.id_player=player.id "
SQL = SQL + "JOIN dbo.show_inventory "
SQL = SQL + "ON dbo.player.id=show_inventory.id_player "
SQL = SQL + "JOIN dbo.inventory_item_list "
SQL = SQL + "ON dbo.show_inventory.id_item=inventory_item_list.id "
SQL = SQL + "WHERE dbo.show_inventory.id_player ='"
SQL = SQL + Request.querystring("pass_id_player") & "' "
SQL = SQL + "AND dbo.event.id = '"
SQL = SQL + Request.querystring("pass_id_event") & "' "
SQL = SQL + "ORDER BY dbo.inventory_item_list.sequence"
```

Tables
    [player](http://ctrlaltdel-usa.net/gtsm/images/support/player.jpg)
    [event](http://ctrlaltdel-usa.net/gtsm/images/support/event.jpg)

I can only post 2 links.  However, the other tables have the following names.  Just change them out at the end of the URL: player_schedule, inventory_item_list, show_inventory

Comment: Why not just use `DISTINCT`?  SELECT DISTINCT field...

Comment: Side Note: Be careful with this approach.  Extremely vulnerable to SQL Injection!

Comment: I'm not sure on the structure/syntax. Rarely used DISTINCT.

Comment: Do you get 4 records or 4 columns?

Comment: 4 records as stated in my original post

Comment: Thanks user2480596...noted!!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Assuming `dbo.event.name` is the data you wanted,

```
SQL = "SELECT dbo.event.name "
SQL = SQL + "FROM dbo.event "
SQL = SQL + "JOIN dbo.player_schedule "
SQL = SQL + "ON dbo.event.id=dbo.player_schedule.id_event "
SQL = SQL + "JOIN dbo.player "
SQL = SQL + "ON dbo.player_schedule.id_player=player.id "
SQL = SQL + "JOIN dbo.show_inventory "
SQL = SQL + "ON dbo.player.id=show_inventory.id_player "
SQL = SQL + "JOIN dbo.inventory_item_list "
SQL = SQL + "ON dbo.show_inventory.id_item=inventory_item_list.id "
SQL = SQL + "WHERE dbo.show_inventory.id_player ='"
SQL = SQL + Request.querystring("pass_id_player") & "' "
SQL = SQL + "AND dbo.event.id = '"
SQL = SQL + Request.querystring("pass_id_event") & "' "
SQL = SQL + "GROUP BY dbo.event.name "
SQL = SQL + "ORDER BY dbo.inventory_item_list.sequence"
```

Comment: I got the same result with 4 items listed

Comment: Check edited answer, though I'm really guessing at your schema.

Comment: Check original post as I added screenshots of the table structure.

Comment: SQL = "SELECT dbo.event.name" <<<< doesn't work... but hopefully with the table screenshots it'll provide a better picture.

Comment: There was a missing space (that is now fixed). Did you have bad syntax, or wrong results?

Comment: it's actually the contents of show_inventory that I'd like to display.

Comment: When using that last edit of code.. "name" is not found. I've updated my original post to include the table structures.